# generating graphs in one image

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am making about 18 graphs in R and I want them to render in one image. I get an error message about size.

In the past I have used `par(mfrow = c(2,2))` and such simple stuff to generate multiple graphs in one rendering.

So, in what I am doing I want to generate a six times three rendering. So, it would look something like six rows and three columns. I thought it should be simple, by using `par(mfrow = c(6,3))`.

In R when I try to do `par(mfrow = c(6,3))` I get

> "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" .

I tried to solve this problem by using 3 times 3 instead of 6 times 3. This would result in half of what I want, but then I can just combine them through MSpaint. A bit of a hassle, but it does the job to produce the final 6 times 3. Is there an easier way to do this, to allow this to be done in R?

Comment: Unsurprisingly, it's because your "figure margins (are) too large". The first step is to probably reduce the size of your margins - `par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))` or make your device dimensions much bigger to account for the extra margins - `dev.new(width=16,height=10)`. But admittedly combining plots like this in a big array is probably better suited for a grid-based plotting method like `lattice` or `ggplot2`

Comment: I would also suggest faceting using `ggplot2`. But 6x3 facets could end up looking rather crowded and visually difficult to comprehend. It might help to provide example data and code, so we can judge the effectiveness of the visualisation and make suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize if this is redundant with older threads discussing the merits of the different plotting mechanisms in R. However, I think it may be worth showing solutions for "simple" multipanel plots with the three major plotting mechanisms. The recommendation of  @thelatemail about using `lattice` or `ggplot2` for these type of plots is right on the money and perhaps this answer illustrates why.

Still, even though base R may require the most tweaking through `par()` and requires familiarity with the functions found with `library(help = "graphics")`, I tend to use base R to generate publication quality figures. I found an excellent discussion of multipanel plotting with base R by [Sean Anderson](https://seananderson.ca/) in this [PDF](https://seananderson.ca/courses/11-multipanel/multipanel.pdf).

To start, generate some reproducible data (**always** a good idea) composed of 18 sets of 20 x-y pairs in a single data.frame with suitable group labels and an index `uid`. The plots will show the x-y data and add a smoothing line.

```
  set.seed(1234)
  x <- seq(0, 9, length.out = 20)
  y <- replicate(6, (x-5) + rnorm(x))
  y <- c(y, replicate(6, 5*sin(x) + rnorm(x)))
  y <- c(y, replicate(6, 5*atanh((9-x)/10) + rnorm(x)))

  a <- gl(3, 120, labels = c("A","B","C")) # these factors are handy
  b <- gl(6, 20, length = 360)
  uid <- as.numeric(b:a)

  df <- data.frame(x, y, a, b, uid)
  rm(x, y, a, b, uid) # prevent use of variables outside of the data.frame
```

In my experience, R Studio is bit more demanding (controlling) with regards to plots. I'm not sure how well this code will run under R Studio. With that warning, an appropriately sized plotting device will be created to start.

```
  dev.new(width = 6.5, height = 6.5)
```

First, a base R solution using `par(mfrow = c(6, 3)` and the outer margin parameter (`oma`). This also makes atypical use of the `legend()` function to add a titles to each panel.

```
  par(mfrow = c(6, 3), mar = c(0,0,0,0), oma = c(6, 6, 2, 2))
  ylim <- range(df$y) # to ensure uniformly sized plots
  ncol <- 3 # number of columns to the plot
  for(u in 1:18) {
    sel <- df$uid == u
    plot(y ~ x, df, subset = sel, ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, ylim = ylim)
    box() # adds a "frame" or "box" around each plot
    xy <- loess.smooth(df$x[sel], df$y[sel], span = 1/3)
    lines(xy)
    if ((u - 1)%%ncol == 0) axis(2, las = 1)
    if ((u - 1)%/%ncol == 5) axis(1)
    leg.text <- paste(unique(df$a[sel]), unique(df$b[sel]), sep = ":")
    legend("top", leg.text, bty = "n")
  }
  mtext("x", side = 1, outer = TRUE, line = 3)
  mtext("y", side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = 3)
```

[image: base multipanel plot]
Both `ggplot2` and `lattice` will return objects that can be further refined. A solution with `lattice` in that spirit is shown here.

```
  library(lattice)
  o <- xyplot(y ~ x | b:a, df, as.table = TRUE, layout = c(3, 6))
  o <- update(o, type = c("p", "smooth"), span = 1/3)
  plot(o)
```

[image: lattice multipanel plot]
The syntax as well as the embedded aesthetic principles differ among the plotting mechanisms. This is obvious in a basic `ggplot2` solution.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(b:a ~ ., ncol = 3)
  g <- g + geom_smooth()
  plot(g)
```

[image: ggplot2 multipanel plot]
The choice of which mechanism to use is personal one. I mentioned that I often favor base graphics for fine control. For preparing plots to be displayed on a monitor, `ggplot2` gives screen-friendly images with little fuss. For repeatedly *exploring* multidimensional data, I find `lattice` to be the most useful. This can be illustrated by the time required to execute the plotting code (without loading the library). The output of `system.time()` for each was captured and shown here (from a Windows i7 machine).

```
  rbind(base = time1, lattice = time2, ggplot = time3)[, 1:3]
>         user.self sys.self elapsed  
> base         0.05     0.03    0.10  
> lattice      0.23     0.03    0.28  
> ggplot       1.27     0.05    1.38
```

Comment: Really thorough and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ggplot2. Here is a [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html).

You will probably want to use `grid.arrange()`. I have used this frequently and it has worked quite well. The link I provided above gives details on its usage.